# Using Incron to trigger a script only once under certain conditions

Tags: incron

I have setup incron to watch over a directory it triggers a bash script if a file is created in this directory:

```
/home/benji/Nextcloud/Buchhaltung/test/ IN_CREATE       ./media/benji/Storage/Programme/Scripts/autoconvert/nc_autoconvert_function
```

Unfortunately if I copy multiple files into this directory each time the script starts and does it's job. So far so good, because this is what Incron seems to be made for.
In my case the problem is, that the script includes some loops on the files existing in the directory which is watched by incron. Some of the files which are "too slow" to be processed, are reprocessed by the second or any following executions of the same script and hence files are duplicated.
I wonder what would be a nice solution to that?

Here is the script itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variables for you to declare!
dir="/home/benji/Nextcloud/Buchhaltung/test/"
tag="Buchung"
images="(*.png|*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.JPG|*.JPEG|*.webp)"
format=".pdf"
dateformat=+"%Y"-"%m"-"%d"
convert="convert"
copy="cp"

#Preperations
shopt -s extglob
#sleep 10
#Actual script starting here – do not change unless you know what you are doing ;)
function process_files() {
  command=$1
  filestoproccess=$2
  for f in $dir*$filestoproccess; do #loop on every file that has extension $images
    if [[ "$f" != *$tag* ]]; then #exclude files of the loop with filename including $tag
      mdate="$(date -r "$f" $dateformat)"
      if [[ -f $dir""$tag"_"$mdate$format"" ]]; then #checks if "Buchung_$mdate.pdf" matches an already existing file in $dir
        for e in $f; do
          collisions="$(ls "$dir" | grep "$mdate")"
          max=$(echo ${collisions//@($tag|$mdate|$format|_)} | tr " " "\n" | sort -nr | head -1)
          suffix=$(expr $max + 1)
          $command "$e" "$dir""$tag"_"$mdate"_"$suffix$format"
          rm "$e"
        done
      else
        $command "$f" "$dir""$tag"_"$mdate""$format"
        rm "$f"
    fi
    else
      echo $f" - Already processed!"
    fi
done
}

process_files $convert $images
process_files $copy $format
```

Comment: This is a coding question not really about Ubuntu. Generally I'd create a lock file where the process stores the file it is processing (or has processed). And all new instances need to first check if the file is not in there.  But I generally would not do it like that. I'd have 1 instance do 1 file and not loop the directory. Python has modules that do this a lot better (as in better readable code) where you only need roughly 10 lines of personal code.

Comment: here is an example: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/04/monitoring-filesystem-python-and-pyinotify/  delete all but IN_CREATE and it is 12 lines of code. All you need are the 2 lines you use: the cp and the convert

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I know not much about python…I wonder if there is a way within the script to check the pid if an instance of the script is running and write to a variable. If that variable is/becomes empty the rest of the script runs…Know what I mean?

Comment: Well it is simpeler than bash ;)  and yes there is... it is called a pid lock file Here is an example for bash https://gist.github.com/darth-veitcher/f47eb0a52ae42a1c5e9a65adca460723   Python does it in 2 lines https://pypi.org/project/pidlock/ ;)

Comment: Oh thanks! – If it is simpler – good for me  – Did not know about pid lock file. But it seems to be the solution to my problem...thanks!

Comment: I just found out that flock is a very good command to be implemented within the incrontab! – check this out: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-ensure-instance-running